# Describe response type application/pdf in openapi-generator-cli

Tags: javascript, openapi, openapi-generator

I have API endpoint, that returns pdf file.
Trying to describe something like this:

```
  /SupportingDocument/document/{documentId}:
    get:
      tags: [Company, Document]
      operationId: getDocument
      summary: Get document by id
      security:
        - JWTAuth: []
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: documentId
          required: true
          schema: { type: string }
      responses:
        200:
          description: A PDF file
          content:
            application/pdf:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
        404: { $ref: '#/components/responses/InternalServerError' }
        500: { $ref: '#/components/responses/InternalServerError' }
```

But generator ends up with

```
...
            return fetch(basePath + localVarFetchArgs.url, localVarFetchArgs.options).then((response) => {
                if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                    return response.json(); // trying to return json, but this is pdf file starting from "%...."
                } else {
                    throw response;
                }
            });
```

And then i catch error like "Unexpected token % at position 0...".
How can i describe it right?

UPD:
I need it to work something like this:

```
            return fetch(basePath + localVarFetchArgs.url, localVarFetchArgs.options).then((response) => {
                if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                    return response; // just response, not json
                } else {
                    throw response;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you please add the entire error to your question?